# Program dies on casting int to double. Can't figure out why it segfaults

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, segmentation-fault

For IP reasons I cannot post the actual code, but here's the gist:

```
 ...
 double valueA = 0.0;
 double valueB = 0.0;
 section_t * section = &some_global_table[counter].section;
 if (NULL == section) continue;
 else
 {
      for (subsecnum = 0; subsecnum < section->entries; subsecnum++)
      {
          valueA = (double) section->subsection[subsecnum].value //CRASHES HERE
          valueB = (double) section->subsection[subsecnum+1].value; // subsecnum + 1 is a valid entry
          ...//do something with values//...
      }
 }
 ...
```

The above code is called multiple times, depending on the section required,

Recently I was stress testing our application using jmeter - 150 threads on a continuous loop (it's a server app), and it crashed (SIGSEGV). Running it through GDB pointed me to the line marked `//CRASHES HERE`. I've run it through GDB a few times after and it always crashes at the same point.

However: it does NOT always crash on the values in the table. For example, the first time it crashed:

```
counter = 2
subsecnum = 21
```

the second time it crashed:

```
counter = 19
subsecnum = 10
```

and so on...

I've checked and double checked the values for out-of-bounds errors, but that is not it. The values are all valid.

**NOTE**: I found that if I actually copied the entire `some_global_table[counter].section` to a buffer instead of just using a pointer, there is no crash. However, even using a mutex around the read section did not work...

Any help is really appreciated, and if any more detail is required, please let me know.

**EDIT**: The global table is loaded in the beginning, and not changed at any point after, therefore the value of `section->entries` for a particular section will always be the same once the data is loaded.

**EDIT2**: Structure for section_t

```
 typedef struct
 {
     int entries;
     subsection_t * subsections;
 } section_t;

 typedef struct
 {
     int value;
     char title[MAX_LEN_TITLE];
 } subsection_t;

 typedef struct
 {
     char bookname[MAX_LEN_BOOK_TITLE];
     FILE * bookfile;
     section_t section;
 } global_table_t;

 global_table_t some_global_table[MAX_TABLES];
```

**EDIT3**:

```
 Dump of assembler code from 0x4132a1 to 0x413321:
    0x00000000004132a1 <myfunc+389>:    roll   0x0(%rcx)
    0x00000000004132a4 <myfunc+392>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
    0x00000000004132a9 <myfunc+397>:    callq  0x408382 <log>
    0x00000000004132ae <myfunc+402>:    jmpq   0x413517 <myfunc+1019>
    0x00000000004132b3 <myfunc+407>:    mov    -0x68(%rbp),%rax
    0x00000000004132b7 <myfunc+411>:    mov    (%rax),%rax
    0x00000000004132ba <myfunc+414>:    sub    $0x1,%eax
    0x00000000004132bd <myfunc+417>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%rbp)
    0x00000000004132c0 <myfunc+420>:    movl   $0x0,-0x5c(%rbp)
    0x00000000004132c7 <myfunc+427>:    jmpq   0x413505 <myfunc+1001>
    0x00000000004132cc <myfunc+432>:    mov    -0x68(%rbp),%rax
    0x00000000004132d0 <myfunc+436>:    mov    0x10(%rax),%rdx
    0x00000000004132d4 <myfunc+440>:    mov    -0x5c(%rbp),%eax
    0x00000000004132d7 <myfunc+443>:    cltq   
    0x00000000004132d9 <myfunc+445>:    shl    $0x4,%rax
    0x00000000004132dd <myfunc+449>:    lea    (%rdx,%rax,1),%rax
 => 0x00000000004132e1 <myfunc+453>:    mov    0x8(%rax),%eax
    0x00000000004132e4 <myfunc+456>:    mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
    0x00000000004132e7 <myfunc+459>:    mov    -0x68(%rbp),%rax
    0x00000000004132eb <myfunc+463>:    mov    0x10(%rax),%rax
    0x00000000004132ef <myfunc+467>:    lea    0x10(%rax),%rdx
    0x00000000004132f3 <myfunc+471>:    mov    -0x5c(%rbp),%eax
    0x00000000004132f6 <myfunc+474>:    cltq   
    0x00000000004132f8 <myfunc+476>:    shl    $0x4,%rax
    0x00000000004132fc <myfunc+480>:    lea    (%rdx,%rax,1),%rax
    0x0000000000413300 <myfunc+484>:    mov    0x8(%rax),%eax
    0x0000000000413303 <myfunc+487>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
    0x0000000000413306 <myfunc+490>:    cvtsi2sdl -0x8(%rbp),%xmm0
    0x000000000041330b <myfunc+495>:    movsd  %xmm0,-0x50(%rbp)
    0x0000000000413310 <myfunc+500>:    cvtsi2sdl -0x4(%rbp),%xmm0
    0x0000000000413315 <myfunc+505>:    movsd  %xmm0,-0x40(%rbp)
    0x000000000041331a <myfunc+510>:    mov    -0x68(%rbp),%rax
    0x000000000041331e <myfunc+514>:    mov    0x10(%rax),%rdx

    rax            0xa80    2688
    rbx            0x7fffc03f9710   140736418780944
    rcx            0x4066c00000000000   4640607572284407808
    rdx            0x0  0
    rsi            0xfffff00000000  4503595332403200
    rdi            0x7fffc039e8f0   140736418408688
    rbp            0x7fffc039e9f0   0x7fffc039e9f0
    rsp            0x7fffc039e950   0x7fffc039e950
    r8             0x13 19
    r9             0x1  1
    r10            0x9  9
    r11            0x7fffc039e848   140736418408520
    r12            0x7fffedd86d60   140737183772000
    r13            0x7fffc03f99d0   140736418781648
    r14            0x4  4
    r15            0x7  7
    rip            0x4132e1 0x4132e1 <myfunc+453>
    eflags         0x10202  [ IF RF ]
    cs             0x33 51
    ss             0x2b 43
    ds             0x0  0
    es             0x0  0
    fs             0x0  0
    gs             0x0  0
```

Comment: I would guess that either "section" or "subsectnum" is invalid.

Comment: A debugger and quick examination of the validity of `some_global_table[counter].section` would probably shed some light on this. Any number of invalid indications could be the cause.

Comment: I don't think a cast-to-`double` makes it crash. Pointer operations are much more suspicious.

Comment: @Sagar 1. You said the global table is loaded in the beginning. Does it mean that all `sections` are initialized and no `sections` are added/removed later? 2. Is the `(double)` neccessary, e.g. what's the type of `subsection.value`?

Comment: Uh, how are you using a fractional value for subsecnum?

Comment: What does the disassembly look like around the instruction which crashes?  Also, what is the data type of `subsecnum`?  It looks like it should be an integer (it's used as an index after all), but you're claiming it has floating-point values like `21.2`.

Comment: @HotLicks I've checked the values and they are valid. Also, that was an error on my part - the subsecnums are integers, not floating points. I made a mistake in the example.

Comment: @j.holetzeck yes, all values are loaded in the beginning, and nothing is added/removed/changed after that.

Comment: `subsecnum < section->entries` in the loop condition, and then `section->subsection[subsecnum+1].value` looks suspicious. Unless of course the section has at least `section->entries + 1` entries.

Comment: @wildplasser You can ask for the structure without the sarcasm. I can create something similary to what I have. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield it is an integer. My example was wrong.

Comment: @DanielFischer I completely concur with your comment. If anything I would expect that to be **`subsecnum`** if it is a traditional C/C++ array and someone phat-phingered the `+` vs. `-` key.

Comment: @wildplasser added the typedefs

Comment: @DanielFischer section->entries is the max it can go to, therefore the `subsecnum+1` is actually ok. Sorry, could have made that clearer

Comment: @Sagar not that it will matter, but the only thing really left type-wise that you haven't provided is the type of the structure for the global table. Can you tack that on to your typedef addendum. Thanks.

Comment: If it is the maximum to go, that would be just bad practice, IMHO. It would also make it impossible to change the section_t.entries to an unsigned type, which would be my first step. BTW: I see that you are using threading. Do you have the global struct or at least the ->entries field protected by semafores?

Comment: @Sagar: Please post the disassembly around the crashing instruction, as well as the current register state.  These can be obtained from gdb by running the commands `disas $eip-64,$eip+64` and `info reg` (replace `$eip` by `$rip` if you're running on x86-64, or replace it by `$pc` if you're running on a PowerPC or ARM architecture).

Comment: @AdamRosenfield will do. getting it right now.

Comment: So I'm still unclear on something... why the check for NULL on the `section` pointer if it is being assigned the address of a non-dynamic section member held in a table of static structures? That should *never* be NULL so long as `counter` is valid, and if `counter` is not valid (i.e. out-of-range) you can't rely on NULL anyway, as the results are undefined behavior. So why the NULL check?

Comment: The nullcheck indeed makes no sense. And the absense of synchronisation (it is a global struct in a multithreaded program) makes it even clearer: impossible to solve.

Comment: @wildplasser agree about the NULL check, will find out more about that. as far as synchronisation - there is only reading, no writing to the structure and that's why there's no mutex locking unlocking around this. however, I did that try, but it did not help.

Comment: thanks all! I'll post back if I find the problem, or even something close.

Comment: According to the disassembly, the value of `section->subsections` is `NULL`.  As others have said, the `NULL` check for `section` makes no sense -- perhaps you meant to check `section->subsections` for `NULL` instead?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Thats a *fantastic* idea. Makes me wish I spoke `asm` as fluently as the some of you do. Been to long. In theory one would hope that if there are no subsections `entries` would be zero, but I'm not relying on anything at this point.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield in that case, why would it would it work if I copy the entire global table into a local buffer and access it from there? I believe that check for subsection being null is there already, but will confirm.

Answer (score 4):

My conjecture, and yes it is a stretch, is that it isn't *necessarily* the subsection that is wrong; it is the `counter` argument and the subsequent dereferences that ensue. You have a `counter` that is looping through what we hope is your global table. One would hope it is not exceeding `MAX_TABLES-1`, as doing so introduces undefined behavior. Though your sample did not include the loop I can only assume it looks something like this:

```
size_t counter=0;
for (;counter < some_upper_limit; ++counter)
{
    double valueA = 0.0;
    double valueB = 0.0;
    section_t * section = &some_global_table[counter].section;
    if (NULL == section)
        continue;
    else
    {
        for (subsecnum = 0; subsecnum < section->entries; subsecnum++)
        {
            valueA = (double) section->subsection[subsecnum].value //CRASHES HERE
            valueB = (double) section->subsection[subsecnum+1].value; // subsecnum + 1 is a valid entry
          ...//do something with values//...
        }
    }
}
```

Note the check for NULL? The question is, *Why take the address of a fixed member of a structure in a fixed global array of those structures, then "validate" it against NULL??*

This literally looks like you're assuming if `counter` is an index not within `[0..MAX_TABLES-1]` then the address of the structure held at the array dereferenced with that index will somehow be NULL. That *cannot* be guaranteed. Chances are the memory you're referencing is "valid", but certainly not defined.

Therefore, you are now toting around a completely illegitimate pointer, which *may* go kerboom as soon as it is dereferenced (or spawn a chorus line of sewer rats singing a chorus line of "One"; thus the nature of undefined behavior =).

Everyone has been cajoling around the idea that `subsection[subsecnum]` is somehow the root of the cause of this, but I submit to you that `section->` is the real problem, because `section` is garbage, and `section` is garbage because an undefined assumption of an out-of-range induced array index (`counter`) made it so.

So how could `counter` be bad? One way would be concurrency. If this indeed is a multi-threaded application and `counter` is a variable somehow scoped for access from multiple threads concurrently, it is not protected at all. One loop could increment it *after* another loop tested it, thereby invalidating the latter's test. It may be the very reason you thought putting the NULL-check in was a way to circumvent that concurrency side-effect. I honestly don't know.

But that is where I would start looking. Dump `counter` to a debug log if it is not used concurrently. Make sure it is within range. If it *is* concurrently accessed, make sure it is protected.

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig. I'll go through the entire source again tomorrow, along with your comments and see if I can find anything.

Comment: @Sagar No problem. I wish you the best of luck in tracking this down.

Comment: +1:  Your answer is no stretch at all.  That's really all that it could be.

Answer (score 3):

I totally agree with WhozCraig.  Additionally:

```
// OK...
for (subsecnum = 0; subsecnum < section->entries; subsecnum++) {
  // Also OK (provided "section" and "subsection" are both allocated and initialized)
  valueA = (double) section->subsection[subsecnum].value //CRASHES HERE
  // Are you *sure* "subsecnum + 1" is a valid entry?
  valueB = (double) section->subsection[subsecnum+1].value;
```

ALSO:

"Gdb", as it sounds like you already know, is your Friend.  It wouldn't help to single-step through your loop, and "print" array and pointer references at various points to make sure everything's OK (and stays OK).

IMHO...

Comment: +1 I concur this could well be a problem as well. We honestly can't say much beyond that without knowing much more about the program structure than we likely will every find out. But it is a deref-and therefore a potential source, to be sure.

Comment: That is what @Daniel Fisher already commented. It appears the OP stores not the number of elements, but the maximal valid index in the `->entries` field. Weird, I agree ...

Comment: Could also be a negative index (the OP uses signed indexes) hitting the `->entries` field somwhere else.

Comment: @wildplasser This whole thing falls into that classification if you ask me, and had it not been for that NULL-check, I would have just left it in the dark, but it "spoke" to me =P

Comment: @paulsm4 absolutely sure. also, it never actually reaches the end before crashing. last crash: entries = 481, subsecnum = 123

Comment: @Sagar: put some asserts in, and you'll notice. And I would advise you to use unsigned types for all the the counts and indices. It involves some work, but it will halve the number of possible off-by-one's. And it would at least *fail fast*

Comment: @wildplasser already started on that based on your comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned '150 threads' I would guess you have a race condition -- one thread is modifying (perhaps freeing) the section_t while another thread is accessing it.  This would explain why copying things makes the bug appear to go away -- that makes the race hole much smaller.

Since you can get a debugger attached at the crash, try examining the section_t (`p *section`) and try to figure out what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Without the full context, its hard to say.  One thing I would recommend doing is to run your server program under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to check if you are indeed running into a memory overrun or not.  Since you are doing array accesses, I would suspect something amiss there.  As commenters have pointed out, I doubt its any issue with teh casting.